# Setting up a commercial wireless network that supports numerous medium-high bandwidth users?

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth, load-balancer

How would *you* configure a wireless network that needs to provide a decent-speed internet connection to a room full of users?

Imagine a hypothetical establishment, maybe it's a large coffee shop or a bed & breakfast with about 30 users actively using the Internet. A few might be streaming video content and one or two may even be downloading something via BitTorrent.

Let's say this establishment caters to tech professionals, so it's of the utmost importance that the Internet connection appears stable.

1. Since certain users might hog the bandwidth, would I want to install more sophisticated firmware like DD-WRT or Tomato on my router and limit the bandwidth per device?
2. Would I also want two connections and a dual WAN setup for additional bandwidth (particularly at peak hours)?
3. What other important considerations are involved?

Comment: There's nothing special to do, other than get better routers, switches and internet connection. The default congestion control already makes a reasonable effort to limit congestion. Also, consider that most internet traffic is HTTP. Which means most users won't be actively using the network. Limiting bandwidth will only starve certain users while others have plenty of extra bandwidth not being used.

Comment: You'd want to ask this question on Network Engineering. Superuser is aimed at home networks. See [help center](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks, wasn't familiar with that community, always imagined _Superuser_ would be the appropriate place for such a question.